# If a convert converted without knowing that their conversion would be permanent

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, mistakes

Hypothetically, if a convert converted without knowing that their conversion would be permanent (i.e., cannot convert out), does that make the conversion invalid?

Comment: This might be a case of conversion under false principles (or misunderstanding or whatever), that doesn't count. Welcome to Mi Yodeya, by the way.

Comment: The doubt most likely would only apply if he actually thought it’s not permanent, as opposed to if he was just unaware.